# How to exclude git commit hash (7-char long hex string) from spelling?

Tags: neovim, spell-checking, spelling

I use neovim as editor for git. Especially when rebasing it is hard to focus on the important things because the spell check highlights the commit hashes.

Therefore I'm trying to exclude the 7-char long hex strings from spell checking with:

```
syntax match NoSpellGitHash /\x\{7}/ contains=@NoSpell
```

This does not seem to have any effect because e.g. `1278fbd` or `bdbbe1f` still get the bad-spell highlighting. If I search for my pattern with `/\x\{7}` it does however find the hashes.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: See here: https://github.com/vim/vim/pull/7221

Comment: Yeah, I was going to say that that text is already matched in Vim's syntax/gitrebase.vim ... `syn match   gitrebaseHash   "\v<\x{7,}>" contained`. I wonder if you can override that (e.g. in `after` config) while waiting for the patch to get released.

Comment: I'm using neovim though. I tried copying the match rules from the diff but no success so far.

Comment: BTW, the question's first sentence..."as editor for Vim". Vim? Or git? I suggest you edit that so other people don't have to read it multiple times like I did.

Comment: Can you try the same changes with Vim. If it's working with Vim but not Neo than the latter must have a bug. (They use the same syntax files generally. Certainly the git syntax files look identical).

Comment: I used the git.vim with original `vim -U git.vim` and added `set spell; set spelllang=en_us` but abc123 is still marked as typo.